# How to align horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have two objects that I want to align to horizontally, like, same row/in-line.

How to do that? Row span didn't work to me. Thank you

Like this:

[image]

Here's the [site](http://goo.gl/49elyC)

CSS:

```
.metaslider {
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
left: 300px;
margin-top:0px;
}
```

Comment: You are expected to put the relevant code within the OP so that the question remains useful.  In this case, as soon as you fix your site, the question becomes useless to others.  Read and follow:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the id fbuilder and the class huge_it_slideshow_image_wrap_1 in one division. Give that div width:100%. after that add float:left in the id fbuilder and class huge_it_slideshow_image_wrap_1. This will make both in same line. I hope this will work. If not, let us know.

Comment: but i can't find huge_it_slideshow_image_wrap_1 in css file

Comment: May be its added from js file. Anyway directly write .huge_it_slideshow_image_wrap_1 {float:left} .

Comment: pls see the update question. I change the plugin. I try to put margin-top:0px; but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Well add this css to `cp_cff_clean`

```
float: left;
```

Then add this css too to `huge_it_slideshow_image_wrap_1`

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
```

This should work fine, tested on your site

Comment: I can't find huge_it_slideshow_image_wrap_1 in .css hmm

Comment: I mean the container in right side containing the slide show

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solve now, by putting this

```
position: absolute;
right: 50px;
top: 300px;
z-index: -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your blocks are fixed height and width you can use absolute position on css 
your Parent stage ( container ) must have relative position and other element have absolute .

Look at my code on css , element have top: 50% for 50%  from their container , for align vertically you should add add half mines of height element . If you want that element align horizontally you should do that for with

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="LeftBlock">Left Block</div>
    <div class="RightBlock">Right Block</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.Container { 
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 500px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 10px; 
    height: 300px; 
    margin: 0px auto; 
    position:relative
}

div.LeftBlock, div.RightBlock { 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 150px; 
    background: #fc0; 
    border: 1px solid #B99504; 
    text-align: center; 
    line-height:150px; 
    color:#333;
    font-family: tahoma;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; 
    margin-top: -75px; 
}

div.LeftBlock { 
    left:10px; 
}

div.RightBlock { 
    right: 10px; 
}
```

[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s7r88tam/)